# can i initialize const instance so that i can use it as const to initialize array?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, constants

(small reference):

```
template<typename T>
struct IVector2 {
    T x, y;

    IVector2(T x, T y) :
        x(x), y(y) { }
};
```

Is there a way to do this:

```
    static const IVector2<int> floors;  // lowest / highest floor

    std::vector<std::array<IPerson, floors.x - floors.y>> requestQueue;
```

I need to initialize array size to be diffrence between floors.x and floors.y.
i've been searching for answer on how to initialize floors and i've got this

```
const IVector2<int> IElevatorHandler::floors(-1, 4);
```

but that doesn't do it.

Comment: the size of `std::array` should be available at compile time, but in your example, it is not. If  you need a container with run-time dynamic size, then use `std::vector` instead of `std::array`.

Comment: I think you can with ```literal classes```

Comment: You just need to use `constexpr`: https://godbolt.org/z/HdqYvN

Answer (score 1):

You can try using literal classes for that. I made a few changes to your code

```
template<typename T>
struct IVector2 {
    T x, y;

    constexpr IVector2(T x, T y) : //constexpr constructor
        x(x), y(y) { }
};


static constexpr IVector2<int> floors(10,1);  // Initialized constexpr object. Now available at compile time
```

Comment: problem is that floors is a class member and compiler has problem with that solution.

Comment: Try something like this ```class I{
  
    static constexpr IVector2<int> floors = {10,1}; 
    std::vector<std::array<int, floors.x - floors.y>> requestQueue;
    
};``` Now it's inside another class